# How to get Terraform version name inside TF files?

Tags: terraform

I want to record the Terraform version used to build the system in few places (e.g. tags or generated code files).

How's it possible to do something like:

```
locals {
    tags = {
        terraform_version = # what goes in here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the version should be specified in the `terraform` block. Also, it is present in the state file.

Comment: You have to add it manually. There is no any build in variable in TF that would give you the TF version automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include the version of Terraform in your tags which is a perfectly legitimate thing to do, you can use a null_resource to get the version, write it to a file, and then pull that into your tag:

```
locals {
  tags = {
    terraform_version = data.local_file.terraform_version.content
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "get_terraform_version" {
  triggers = { always_run = "${timestamp()}" }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo $(terraform --version | sed 1q) > ${path.module}/terraform_version.txt"
  }
}

data "local_file" "terraform_version" {
  filename   = "${path.module}/terraform_version.txt"
  depends_on = [null_resource.get_terraform_version]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The lock file is used to ensure that TF versions remain consistent. Add it to version control and you will always know which version was used.

https://www.terraform.io/language/files/dependency-lock